# How do I execute Mono IDE on Windows to start programming?

Tags: c#, windows, mono, gtk

So I'm trying to find some executable file that matches Mono IDE GUI for Windows and the closest file is monow.exe, but after execution it raises an ERR like "program won't start up, libmonoboehm-2.0.dll is missing".
To be honest, all I have after installing https://download.mono-project.com/archive/5.12.0/windows-installer/mono-5.12.0.301-gtksharp-2.12.45-win32-0.msi is a bunch of files under folder %program_files%\Mono\ and a link in W7 menu to a console .exe file. 
**What do I have to do to run the Mono GUI?** 
I've been searching that missing DDL file over the internet but no luck.
Any help or guideness is really appreciated as I don't have any experience with this IDE. Will be my first time, LOL!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use Mono IDE rather than VS Code or Visual Studio?

Comment: Well, I'm moving to Linux and as far as I know there's no VS for this OS, but maybe I'm wrong... I want to preserve my project structure the Mono's way in the process.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Comment: You might refer to https://github.com/lextm/monodevelop-windows/issues/1 to grab a test build.

Answer (score 0):

You installed the mono runtime not the mono development tools.
also "MonoDevelop for Windows is available from source only" as stated here 
https://www.monodevelop.com/download/

so you will need a working toolchain already to use the monodevelop ide. 
There is however a precompiled binary linked on the issue page https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/issues/4653

You can also build your own with these instuctions
https://www.monodevelop.com/developers/building-monodevelop/

Comment: Hmm, precompiled version didn't work on my W7. I think it's because it has been compiled in W10 and the article says. I'm affraid I'll have to compile it myself under W7 using those instructions. Let's see if I'm able to...